# Getting the value of an element by an ID in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

ive pretty new to javascript,html and all that stuff and currently trying to create a chrome extension that gets the value of an element and displays it in the chrome extension. However i get [object object] instead of the value, i feel like I'm on the correct path but also feel way off at the same time.

popup.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', function (evt) {
    chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        file: 'payload.js'
    });;
});

// Listen to messages from the payload.js script and write to popout.html
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = message;
});
```

payload.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.getElementById("priceblock_ourprice"));
```

Comment: you are passing the object itself to your `chrome.runtime.sendMessage()` function. That is why it shows `[object object]`

Comment: How would you send the value of the object?

Comment: It depends on the `priceblock_ourprice` element.

Comment: the element is just a span with text

Comment: then you can do something like this `chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.getElementById("priceblock_ourprice").innerText)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get text from HTML you should use `.innerHTML` or `.innerText`

```js
const text = document.getElementById("priceblock_ourprice");

console.log(text.innerHTML);
console.log(text.innerText);
```

```html
<h1 id="priceblock_ourprice">Hello World</h1>
```